# Kotlin JUnit Rules

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin M13, this was an acceptable way to create a JUnit rule:

`@Rule @publicField val temp = TemporaryFolder()`

Now that `@publicField` has been deprecated, how else can this be achieved?  The IDE hint suggests replacing `@publicField` with `lateinit`, but `lateinit val`'s are no longer allowed, and I'm not sure this would help even if they were.

Answer (score 23):

The answer as of Kotlin 1.0 is as follows:

```
@Rule @JvmField val temp = TemporaryFolder()
```

[`@JvmField`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-field/) exposes the backing field with the same visibility as the property, ergo a public field for the JUnit rule to use.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumble's on this. I believe the approach with JJunit5 would be using @TempDir.
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.4.2/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/io/TempDir.html

If you would need share the TempDir with tests, it must be a static property of the class. Static for java or within a companion Object for Kotlin

Answer (score -4):

Just guessing, but the following might work (with `var`):

```
@Rule lateinit var temp = TemporaryFolder()
```

I would try asking at kotlin's slack http://t.co/xpQXUKaDvP
Currently it's the fastest way to fix anything.

Comment: It does not, JUnit does not see temp as a field in this case, because it isn't actually a field.  There is a hidden backing field in there somewhere, and the trick will be how to apply an annotation to it.

Comment: Sorry, @jkschneider, did you actually checked it to work? Because according to the docs it creates a field and should do the trick. Unfortunately I do not work with JUnit myself.